# How to convert Base64 string to file(Docs) in c# and save it in server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, base64, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on an app where I receive uploaded documents as Base64 string, now I have to convert it to the original format and save it somewhere in application("~/files/docs/")

```
foreach (var fat in files)
    {
       var fileContent = fat.file;
                                           
       string FileExt = Path.GetExtension(fat.name).ToUpper();
                                           
       if (FileExt == ".PDF" || FileExt == ".PPT" || FileExt == ".DOC" || FileExt == ".DOCX" || FileExt == ".XLSX" || FileExt == ".XLS" || FileExt == ".JPG"){}
    }
```

can someone guide me on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay i figured it out

```
   string mystr = fileContent.Replace("base64,",string.Empty);

                                               
    var testb = Convert.FromBase64String(mystr);

                                                
   var file = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/"+fat.name);
   System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, testb);
```

This works, just writing the base64 works but javascript prefixes every base64 string with "base64," text because of which you cannot write the file unless you remove it, so I used string replace to achieve it and its writing fine after. i have tested this with pdf,doc and pptx files and they all work.

Comment: *but javascript prefixes every base64 string with "base64,"* - in data uris you can find "base64," in front of the data, e.g. `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...`, but not generally in javascript base64 encoded strings, at least I've never read about that. So you receive a part of a data uri? Please clarify.

Comment: @jps yes I'm receiving a part of data URI and then replacing the "base64," part with an empty string before writing the bytes to my local folder. I'm sorry I don't have much experience with Javascript and base64 encoding-decoding, this is my first job as a web developer, I only have 3 months of experience in c# and asp.net MVC and because it was self-learned I lack so many skills and knowledge so I'm trying to learn new things as I go.